# How to sort ListFragment and display both accednding and descending order in the same tab in tab layout in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs

I have a tabbed layout with 3 tabs. All tabs are loaded with List Fragments. I need to sort the List Fragment in both ascending and descending order. Display both within the same tab. When we click the tab, it should sort in ascending order. If the same tab is re-selected, it to sort in descending order and display the result.

Is it possible to nest List-Fragment within a tab ?

Comment: Have you tried onTabReselected? Why not keep a variable like sortAscending = true; then when you come back, if it is true, set to false;

Comment: I have tried onTabReselected.                     public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                        if(tab.getPosition()==2 && f == true){
                            tab.setIcon(R.drawable.up_arrow);

Comment: How can you load the fragments in the same tab on this tab selection event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, we can achieve this by using Collections.reverse(list)

```
    // Here we are using reverse() method
    // to reverse the element order of mylist
    Collections.reverse(mylist);
```